# find matching cell value in another workbook and return matching row content

Tags: search, excel, lookup, vba

I'm new to Excel and VBA and am faced with the following task:

I have two workbooks - `wookbook1.xlsx` contains company names and will hold a macro, and `workbook2.xlsx` which will hold the values I need to match against from `workbook1`. For each company name in `workbook1`, I need to get the row value where a match is found in `workbook2`.

Please help.

Comment: Try exploring the Vlookup() function. But you will have to copy your formula in several cells (one per column you want to retrieve). Make sure you understand Absolute (vs Relative) References, you you want to be efficient.

Answer (score 2):

As iDevlop pointed out in his/her comment, you don't have to use vba but rather a formula.

Here are a few links to help you in building the right formula:

- The `VLOOKUP` formula will help you find the matching value in another array: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php
- The `INDEX` formula will help you find the corresponding row or column (a.k.a. *index*) in another array: http://www.contextures.com/xlfunctions03.html

If you can't get it, please edit your first post with what you tried and a deeper example of what you are trying to do.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Matching cells between sheets of the workbook can be searched using the userform.

When the cell that to be searched is double-clicked,userform opens and  the matching cells  can be seen as sheet name and cell address on the userform listbox control.The selected cell addresses in the listbox become active cell.

[image]

VBA codes of userform:

```
Dim Alan2 As Range, Sayfa As Worksheet
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 2
ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "110;40"
For Each Sayfa In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each Alan2 In Sheets(Sayfa.Name).UsedRange
         If Alan2 = ActiveCell.Value Then
             ListBox1.AddItem Sayfa.Name
             ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = Alan2.AddressLocal(0, 0)
          End If
    Next Alan2
    Next Sayfa
Label1.Caption = " " & "Found Records: " & ListBox1.ListCount
```

[Source and sample file address](https://eksi30.com/search-data-within-entire-workbook-with-userform/)